# LINQ filter by type on list from dictionary value

Tags: c#, linq

Think this is a very basic question, but it's my first LINQ query and I'm completely stuck:

I have a dictionary with string key and list value (see definition below) and want to pull out elements of a list of a particular type having selected the list by the dictionary key.

```
IDictionary<string, IList<MyBaseType>> dataItemMap;
```

Where MySubType extends MyBaseType.

My dodgy query is:

```
string identCode = "foo";

IEnumerable<MySubType> query = 
    from entry in dataItemMap
    where entry.Key == identCode
    select entry.Value.OfType<MySubType>();
```

And the error message (from LinqPad):

```
Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MySubType>>'
to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MySubType>'.
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

The problem is clearly in the entry.Value.OfType<> but how can I specify the lists elements? I'm looking for something like entry.Value.Items.OfType<> ?

thanks.

Comment: I think that needing to use OfType() may be a code smell. Why exactly do you need to get only the objects of a particular sub type?

Comment: @LukeN - I'm using all subtypes of MyBaseType in this list as ~80-90% of cases the type is irrelevant, but there are occasions where I want to access only specific subtypes.  Alternatives? 1) using a nested dictionary keyed by type with the list of individual class instances is overcomplicating, 2) Introducing a class to wrap this would force editing every time a new sub class is introduced.  Not particularly elegant I agree but simple enough - so the smell IMO isn't strong enough to warrant refactoring (...yet).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
IEnumberable<MySubType> query = dataItemMap[identCode].OfType<MySubType>();
```

This will get the list with the given key, and then filter it to return only MySubType elements.

Comment: Doh - of course, using the fact that it's a dictionary is kinda helpful :) Of course, that's assuming the dictionary is using an ordinal comparison, but it's an appropriate assumption...

Comment: Although seeing @Jon Skeet's answer I may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I think you just took a better step back than me :) I've edited my answer to refer to yours, and elaborate on it a bit - there are a couple of caveats to be aware of.

Comment: Switch the accepted answer for the benefit of others finding question as it's so succinct.  Upvoted comments, many thanks to you both, hope that's ok.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I've been focusing on why the existing solution didn't work (and the general problem of "I've got a list of values for each element, and I want to flatten it") rather than taking a step back. As Andy's answer shows, you should almost certainly use the fact that it's a dictionary - turning it from an O(n) operation to O(1) :)

Two caveats:

- Your current code will *always* perform an ordinal, culture-insensitive comparison with `identCode` and the dictionary keys; using the dictionary lookup will use whatever comparer it was constructed with.
- Your current code will return an empty sequence if `identCode` isn't found in the dictionary; the dictionary indexer will throw an exception. You can use `TryGetValue` if you want to avoid that.

Note that if you know that all the elements in the last you're picking are *actually* of the right type, it would probably be better to use `Cast` than `OfType`:

```
var query = dataItemMap[identCode].Cast<MySubType>();
```

I generally prefer `Cast` to `OfType` when both would work, as it means that if my assumptions about the data in the sequence prove incorrect, I find out about it with an exception rather than silently missing data.

Note that `Cast` will also return `null` elements, whereas `OfType` won't.

---

No, the problem isn't in using `OfType<>` - it's that you've ended up with a sequence of sequences, but you're trying to assign that to a single sequence.

Either change the return type, or use another `from` clause to flatten the results:

```
IEnumerable<MySubType> query =  from entry in dataItemMap
                                where entry.Key == identCode
                                from value in entry.Value.OfType<MySubType>()
                                select value;
```

I'd be tempted to use the extension methods directly:

```
var query =  dataItemMap.Where(e => e.Key == identCode)
                        .SelectMany(e => e.Value.OfType<MySubType>());
```